# getopt - capture '?'

Tags: c++, getopt

I'm trying to use getopt in a C++ programme to parse command line arguments.
The arguments are -d xxx, -s xxx and -?.
I'm having trouble capturing the -? argument, which I want to print a standard usage message.

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "?d:s:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'd':
          ...do stuff
            break;
        case 's':
         ... do stuff
            break;
        case '?':
          // From example on GNU page, seems to capture -d, -s when no args provided.
          // Gets here when -d or -s provided, but no arguments for these options.
        default:
          // shut down
}
```

Try as I might, I can't seem to capture the '-?' option on its own. Is there a special trick to catch '?' on its own? Have I provided the correct pattern to getopt (ie. '?d:s:')
At the moment, c is getting set to '?' whenever invalid options are provided, even if '?' is NOT provided on the command line.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The fact that `getopt` uses `?` as a special value is a giveaway to you that you should *not* use it to display the help. That’s what `-h` and `--help` are there for. It pays to adhere to these conventions instead of doing your own thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getopt` uses `'?'` as a special value to mean a missing option value or an unknown option. So I don't think there is any way to use `getopt` to handle '-?'.

I would recommend '-h' for the help message. It's a common convention.

Comment: Thanks john - gotchya, ? is not for use, best to use -h or --help.

Answer (score 0):

`getopt` provides a mechanism for that in the form of [`optopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#index-optopt).

You just need to make sure it matches a valid option (in this case `-?`):

```c
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "?d:s:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'd':
            // do stuff...
            break;
        case 's':
            // do stuff...
            break;
        case '?':
            if (opt == optopt) {
                // do stuff...
            }
        default:
        // ...
    }
}
```